# How to add a linklabel in a PropertyGrid in Windows Forms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, windows-forms-designer, propertygrid, linklabel

we have an information tool that displays information from active directory on a gui. I want to extend that tool to the part that i can click on a text to open a file. I am struggeling with the function to do the text clickable.

The tool was made in Windows Forms and VB.net.

My code to create a category in a propertygrid is:

```
<Description(""),
    Category("UserHistory Log"), [ReadOnly](True), Browsable(True), DisplayName("Computerlog")>
    Public ReadOnly Property ComputerLog() As String
        Get
            Return "press here"
        End Get
    End Property
```

Its like this:

[image]

How can i make it clickable? Do you have any clue?

I read about linklabels. But i am not sure how to implement a linklabel into a propertygrid without drag&drop because the form itself is clear.

Comment: It's not really overly clear exactly what your question is.  At a guess you need to handle the LinkClicked event.  Select Events from the Properties grid of the LinkLabel control, and double click the LinkClicked event to add a handler, then implement your desired actions there.

Comment: There's no built in support for showing a link in the property editor; in addition to the text, you can [show an icon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65821300/3110834), or [show a custom glyph](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48278295/3110834), a [dropdown button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66190762/3110834) or a [dots button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46995087/3110834).

Comment: You can also [handle the click event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38425047/3110834) of grid entries.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built in support for showing a link in the property editor; in addition to the text, you can [show an icon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65821300/3110834), a [custom glyph](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48278295/3110834), a [dropdown button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66190762/3110834) or a [dots button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46995087/3110834).

You can also [handle the click event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38425047/3110834) of grid entries.

Handling the click might be good enough for you. But if you would like to show a link label in the property grid, the following code shows you a nice hack (read dirty hack ), so that when you click on the property it shows the link label:

[image]

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = new Test();
    //For .NET projects the field is _gridView
    //For .NET Framework projects the field is gridView
    var gridView = propertyGrid1.GetType()
        .GetField("gridView",
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
        .GetValue(propertyGrid1);
    var edit = gridView.GetType()
        .GetProperty("Edit",
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
        .GetValue(gridView) as TextBox;

    var linkLabel = new LinkLabel()
    {
        Text = "Click me!",
        LinkArea = new LinkArea(0, 9),
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
        AutoSize = false,
        Visible = propertyGrid1.SelectedGridItem?.PropertyDescriptor?.Name == "MyProperty"
    };
    linkLabel.LinkClicked += (obj, args) =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Link clicked");
    };
    edit.Controls.Add(linkLabel);
    propertyGrid1.SelectedGridItemChanged += (obj, args) =>
    {
        var name = args.NewSelection?.PropertyDescriptor?.Name;
        linkLabel.Visible = name == "MyProperty";
    };
    edit.Enter += (obj, args) =>
    {
        var name = propertyGrid1.SelectedGridItem?.PropertyDescriptor?.Name;
        linkLabel.Visible = name == "MyProperty";
    };
}
```

And this is the test class:

```
public class Test
{
    [ReadOnly(true)]
    public string MyProperty { get; set; } = "Click me!";
    public string AnotherProperty { get; set; } = "Something else";
}
```

To use the code, make sure you bind the event handler to the event.

Answer (score 0):

Another totally different approach, adding DesignerVerbs which shows above description panel, at bottom of property grid:

[image]

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = new Test();
    //For .NET projects the field is _hotcommands
    //For .NET Framework projects the field is hotcommands
    var hotcommands = propertyGrid1.GetType()
        .GetField("hotcommands",
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
        .GetValue(propertyGrid1);

    var clickVerb = new DesignerVerb("Click me!",
        (obj, args) => { MessageBox.Show("Clicked!"); });
    hotcommands.GetType().GetMethod("SetVerbs")
        .Invoke(hotcommands, new object[] {
            propertyGrid1.SelectedObject,
            new []{ clickVerb }
        });
}
```

And you don't need the dummy property:

```
public class Test
{
    public string AnotherProperty { get; set; } = "Something else";
}
```